# Log4j log rotation on tomcat leaks disk space in deleted files

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2

Whenever log4j2's **RollingFileAppender** rotates a log file on my web server (when the first entry is written on a new day) the available disk space shrinks considerably.

I use log4j2 2.5 on tomcat 7.0.55.

**lsof** shows several hundreds of deleted files, which can't be freed because they are in use by tomcat.

For instance, the file **FOP.log** was rotated to **FOP.log.2016-04-13.gz** which apparently worked well, but now

```
lsof -s | grep deleted | grep tomcat
```

shows 270 times the file **FOP.log.2016-04-13** (without the gz suffix). These undeleted files eat up several GB of disk space.

These files are gone as soon as I stop tomcat, but restarting tomcat during business hours is not an option.

Since the file name is that of the intermediate uncompressed log, I assume that there is a problem with compressing the rotated file. And a second problem which copies that file over and over.

Is there a way to prevent this file handle leak?

Here's an excerpt from my log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        ...
        <RollingFile name="FOPLogger" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/FOP.log" filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/FOP.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %c - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
        </RollingFile>
        ...
    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```